# How to count number of user's touch per day?

Tags: android

I want to develop a app. It has a function that can count number of user's touch per day. Of course, it can not run all time with my phone. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."

Comment: I want my phone tell me the number of time I touched on screen per day .

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to write an app that can report the number of times the user touched the screen while you app is on the screen and the user touches your UI.

You have no ability, on Android 4.0+, to spy on the touch input to other apps to see when they are touched.

Comment: Thank, but I think Android Operate System have mechanism to track touch event.

Comment: @user3551948: The OS does. You do not. You are writing an app.